# Update SharePoint fields associated with Content Type using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have been searching and can't seem to find the answer. I have a list in SharePoint, which is a Document Library, and I have associated a Content Type with specific fields to that Document Library.

In SharePoint, if I view the properties of a document in the Document Library, I can view and update the values for the fields associated with the Content Type. However using the Microsoft Graph API as instructed [here for GET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [here for UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I cannot get or update these Content Type related properties for the document, using the following.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}
```

or

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}
```

I have all the right permissions because I am able to get and update the normal fields on the document. I am just unable to do so for fields associated with the Content Type.

Is there a way to do this with Microsoft Graph that I'm not finding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your Content Type fields in the Request Body

```
{
    "fields": {
        "{Field Name}": "{Value}"
    }
}
```

Just ensure you use the Internal Field name of the SP field. Credit to Brett McKenzie and this post [Updating a SharePoint List Item’s Content Type in the Microsoft Graph](https://brettmckenzie.net/2018/09/05/updating-a-sharepoint-list-items-content-type-in-the-microsoft-graph/)

Comment: Wow thanks for the link, that's what I've been looking for. Using the Internal Field name worked.

Comment: ...And you use the PATCH HTTP call.